# Related post by custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I use wordpress acf custom post type to create my custop post type.
this code (in my custop post type page php) to display the related post of a taxonomy type, now i want to display by Custom Field instead of taxonomy. Thank you for helping me solve my problem

```
<?php

global $post;

$current_post_type = get_post_type( $post );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'post_type' => $current_post_type,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);

$rel_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $rel_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<h1 id="recent">Related</h1>
<div id="related" class="group">
    <ul class="group">
<?php
    // The Loop
    while ( $rel_query->have_posts() ) :
        $rel_query->the_post();
?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <article>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                <div class="name-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></div>
                <div class="theExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            </article>
        </a>
        </li>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
    </ul><!-- .group -->
</div><!-- #related -->
<?php
endif;

// Reset the query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query Object accept arguments to query custom field values (more info here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/). So you need the name of your custom field in this example 'location' and then the value you want 'Melbourne' (you will get the value using get_field('location')).

So your args should look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => 'Melbourne'
    'post_type' => $current_post_type,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);
```

Hope this helps